# Rotating a color clip in MoviePy?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, moviepy

I'm trying to rotate a moviepy color clip without animating it, so that it is rotated at the start, and remains rotated until the end of the video.

I tried some code hoping that it would rotate a still image in MoviePy, without animating it.  So that it is rotated by the input angle for the entire duration of the image, ColorClip, or Video.

```
import moviepy.editor as mped
image = mped.ImageClip("image.jpg", duration=3)
image.rotate(20)
image.write_videofile('image_without_rotation.mp4', fps=5)
```

However, this doesn't rotate the still image, because ImageClip doesn't have a rotation function.

This code below rotates until 3 seconds.  and can be adapted for a fixed rotation / non animated by changing 20*t to the a constant like 20.

```
clip = mped.ImageClip('image.jpg')
rotated_clip = (clip.add_mask().fx(mped.vfx.rotate, lambda t: 20*t, expand=False).set_duration(3))
centered_rotated_clip = mped.CompositeVideoClip([rotated_clip.set_pos("center")])
centered_rotated_clip.write_videofile('rotated_image.mp4'), fps=10)
```

However, this code won't work for a moviepy ColorClip.

```
color_clip = mped.ColorClip(size=[300, 300], color=[1 ,1, 1])
rotated_color_clip = (color_clip.fx(mped.vfx.rotate, lambda t: 20, expand=False).set_duration(3))
composited_clip = mped.CompositeVideoClip([rotated_Color_ clip.set_pos("center")])
composited_clip.write_videofile('rotated_clip.mp4', fps=10)
```

instead it will give the following error

```
    raise TypeError("Cannot handle this data type: %s, %s" % typekey)
TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 3), <i8
```

because it reaches this line

```
return np.array( Image.fromarray(pic).rotate(angle, expand=expand),
```

inside pil_rotater.

How can I rotate a moviepy ColorClip by 20 degrees ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update 2: This fix is included in v2.0.0.dev1. Install from pip with `pip install --pre --upgrade moviepy`.

Update: I’ve found the bug, and you can track the progress of the bug fix here: https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/pull/1139

In the mean time, as a workaround, instead of passing `color=[150, 100, 200]` to ColorClip, pass `color=np.array([150, 100, 200]).astype(np.uint8)`.

———

The code

```
image = mped.ImageClip("image.jpg", duration=3)
image.rotate(20)
image.write_videofile('image_without_rotation.mp4', fps=5)
```

doesn't work because `image.rotate()` returns a new clip, so you must do `image = image.rotate(20)`.

This should work for both ImageClips and ColorClips, however it appears that you have found a bug where rotations do not work for ColorClips. The best thing to do would be to report it as an issue at [github.com/zulko/moviepy](https://github.com/zulko/moviepy), or try and find a fix yourself and submit it as a pull request there.

For the time being, create a ColorClip, write it to a file, and then read it in again as an ImageClip.

Comment: Thanks Tom.  I did take a look to try and solve this, and then reported as an issue.  I then saw you'd submitted bugfix and pull request for that.  Thanks for this Tom.  When will a version with this fix be released, so I can use that?   I have tested your fix on my machine and it  works here too.

Is there a way that masks what was behind the clip before it was rotated?  So that it doesn't come out black ?  rotate(20).add_mask() seems to create a black background.

Comment: Hey @OneWorld, I'm glad to see that it worked for you! The version with the fix will most likely be v2.0, which may not be for several weeks, as we are working on several different fairly large changes. See the edit I made to this post that you can use as a workaround until the fix is released.

Comment: I'm not sure about the masks, I've never really used them in moviepy. I'll try and get back to you at some point about it.

Comment: I see that the mask does work.  You just do 

rotatedClip = ColorClip.add_mask().rotate(20)

:-)